# How to set language in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to setup the locales with this:

```
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
    lang: {
        locales: { 
            'en-US' : {
                "dataIterator": {
                    "rowsPerPageText": "Items per page:",
                    "rowsPerPageAll": "All",
                    "pageText": "{0}-{1} of {2}",
                    "noResultsText": "No matching records found",
                    "nextPage": "Next page",
                    "prevPage": "Previous page"
                },
                "dataTable": {
                    "rowsPerPageText": "Rows per page:"
                },
                "noDataText": "No data available"
            } 
        },
        current: 'en-US'
    }
});
```

and then later I change the current locale with:

```
this.$vuetify.lang.current = 'en-US';
```

but I get warnings about Vue not having a translation for the current locale.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Vuetify from CDN (in the browser via a `<script>` tag), Vue has already installed the Vuetify plugin upon loading the script, so calling `Vue.use(Vuetify, ...)` again later actually has no effect. The default (and only) locale available is `en`.

You could still update the available locales in your `App`'s `created` hook:

```
created() {
  this.$vuetify.lang.locales = {
    en: {
      noDataText: 'Nothing'
    },
    es: {
      noDataText: 'Nada'
    }
  }
},
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created() {
    this.$vuetify.lang.locales = {
      en: {
        noDataText: 'Nothing'
      },
      es: {
        noDataText: 'Nada'
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeLocale() {
      const currentLang = this.$vuetify.lang.current;
      this.$vuetify.lang.current = currentLang === 'es'
                                 ? 'en'
                                 : 'es';
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.7"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@1.5.4/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@1.5.4/dist/vuetify.min.css">

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container grid-list-xl>
        <v-btn @click="changeLocale">Change locale</v-btn>
        <div>{{ $vuetify.lang.current }} - {{ $vuetify.t('$vuetify.noDataText') }}</div>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been reported in https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/7644 and seems to be fixed now, as the bootstrap process was rebuilt in v2.0:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify({
    lang: {
      t: (key, ...params) => i18n.t(key, params)
    }
  })
})
```

For a complete example have a look at [this codepen](https://codepen.io/johnjleider/pen/RzgGPR?editors=1011).

Details on the changed bootstrapping to be found in the [migration guide](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/releases-and-migrations/#migration-guide).